# How can I append a single value to every cell in column "A" using Python openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am a Python beginner and I've discovered openpyxl which has become very useful to me already, but I have come to an impasse and cannot find a solution anywhere. Column "A" title is "Region" and has values such as "Canada", "Central", "Northeast", "West", etc. I need to replace every value in the column with the current month name (i.e. April) and then rename the column title as "Month". The following code is what I have tried.

ws['A1':'A-1'] = 'April'

When I run the command, I get "ValueError: A1:A-1 is not a valid coordinate or range"

The number of rows in the report changes every month, so I am not able to try a range such as "A1:A500".

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward

```
ws["A1"] = "Month"
for cell in ws["A"][1:]:
    cell.value = "April"
```

For more sophisticated changes user `ws.iter_rows()` and you probably want to calculate the month automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this will work

```
from openpyxl import *
from datetime import datetime
mydate=datetime.now()
currentYear =mydate.strftime("%B")
wb = load_workbook(r"path\to\your\xlsx\file") 
sheet = wb.active  
all_list=[]
for c in sheet['A']:
   print(c.value)
   all_list.append(c.value)
for data,value in enumerate(all_list):
    data+=1
    sheet["A"+str(data)]=currentYear
sheet['A1']="Month"

wb.save(r"path\to\your\xlsx\file")
```

Comment: This loops over the cells twice.